# Event for when a script tag has been loaded and parsed?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have put together a sort of  tag dependency manager to append script tags in the correct order. The handle when it has been loaded:

```
script = document.createElement('script');
...
document.body.appendChild(script);
script.addEventListener('load', (event) => ...)
```

Within the add event listener handler, it will append the next script tag(s) that dependencies have been met (e.g. slick carousel script tag is dependent on jquery script tag)

Looking at the DOM, I can see that scripts have been appended in the correct order:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

However, I'm occasionally getting errors in slick.min.js complaining that $ (jquery) isn't declared even though the order of script tags is always correct. But if I do a few refreshes, it'll be fine then after a few more refreshes I'll get the same issue. Is 'load' firing when the script has been parsed fully?

Comment: Are you setting the .src before or after attaching the load event?

Comment: I set src before

Comment: In case it  makes a difference, try setting it after

Comment: Yeh I tried, but just the same results

Comment: Is there maybe some issue with your code? I ran this a dozen times and it worked without fail: https://jsfiddle.net/71jx095s/

Comment: Possibly, I can also run it dozens of times too without fail but then occasionally it complains a previous script hasn't loaded (e.g. $ not found)

Comment: Did you check the dev tools' network tab to see what the cause is? Is the script actually loaded or not?

Comment: Not sure. I am here because I was trying to understand when you want to use this technique of adding an event listener to a script object. Anyway, I have seen a similar code and there the script is appended to its parent element at the end, i.e. after having added the listener to it. And that code seems working fine